# ERROR: Invalid Renderer instance given in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm newbie on ruby on rails application, from last few days I'm suffering about `Markdown with Redcarpet` issue, I following this [tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/272-markdown-with-redcarpet?view=asciicast) , I'm don't understanding why showing this error.

> Invalid Renderer instance given

This is my helper:

```
def markdown(text)
  #Redcarpet.new(text).to_html.html_safe
  Redcarpet::Markdown.new(text).to_html
end
```

My View:

```
 <%= markdown(@details.post_details) %>
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'redcarpet'
```

That would help me a lot, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think should work, after following this:

```
  <%= markdown(@details.post_details) %>
```

Should try

```
 <%= raw @details.post_details %>
```

Work for me